# fetch's response is empty even though the request was successful

Tags: javascript, cors, cross-domain, fetch-api

I'm trying to use `fetch` function to retrieve data from server in a client side Javascript code. And I'm using the polyfill version of fetch named [`whatwg-fetch`](https://github.com/github/fetch) in a Chrome (which supports fetch internally).

Here's how I call the function:

```
//Called in a page loaded as http://localhost:3236/
fetch("http://localhost:8080/list", {
         mode: 'no-cors',
         credentials: "include", 
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    });
```

As you can see my application server is not the same as my resource server so I had to set the options for CORS. The problem is that the `response` has got no content:

```
{
    body: null,
    bodyUsed: false,
    headers: Headers,
    ok: false,
    status: 0,
    statusText: "",
    type: "opaque",
    url: "",
}
```

It's in the case that when I turn to network panel and find the request sent, it seems all OK with Status of 200 and the requested data.

How can I find what the problem is?

Comment: Note that Chrome can display blank response data if the expected result was for example `application/json`, but the HTTP response body cannot be parsed for whatever reason (i.e. invalid formatting). In cases like this, I'd generally open up Fiddler and check the raw response.

Comment: Doesn't Chrome's raw response panel count? I can see my desired response there. I only can not receive it in JS!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The clue is in the `opaque` key. The request was successful, but Chrome's CORS restrictions are preventing you from using the returned data. The `no-cors` option is suspect; it shouldn't be necessary if your server is correctly configured for cross-origin requests.

N.B. If you've configured everything correctly but you're experiencing errors while testing the client locally, it may be sufficient to launch Chrome with the `--disable-web-security` flag.

Comment: One question; doesn't `no-cors` and server configurations work interchangeably? I have not read this anywhere but if they don't, then what's the meaning of `no-cors`!?

Comment: @Mehran, I'm not entirely clear on the intended use case for `no-cors`, bu the documentation here explicitly states that JavaScript will not be able to inspect the response payload: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode